# Displaying ImageField in HTML Flask

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, imagefield

I am having some problems getting images from the database and showing them in my webpage.

First of all, I am using `mongoengine`, so here goes (part of) my `models.py`:

```
class Picture(EmbeddedDocument):
    image = ImageField()

class Post(Document):
    ...
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'))
    user = ReferenceField('User', reverse_delete_rule='CASCADE')
    images = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Picture'))
```

Here is the code in my `view` where I save the images:

```
picture = Picture()

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as f:
    f.write(file.read())
    f.flush()
    f.seek(0)
    picture.image.put(f)

picture.save()

post.images.append(picture)

post.save()
```

So, in the HTML page I have the following:

```
<p>{{ post.images[0].image }}</p>
<img src="{{ post.images[0].image }}">
```

The first line outputs: `<ImageGridFsProxy: None>`. The second, obviously, doesn't output a valid image.

Here is what I get when I do `db.post.find(...)` in the mongo shell:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56325c4e66b3f6bf8beb9e03"), ... "images" : [ { "image" : ObjectId("56325c4e66b3f6bf8beb9e04") } ] }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: is post.images[0].image giving a valid url to an image?

Comment: @Ryan if I print post.images[0].image in the view, it gives me this: ValidationError: u'<ImageGridFsProxy: None>' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string

Comment: print post.images[0].image.name
Do you get a path back? If you get just the name (ex: test.jpg), try combining with the path to your temporary files.

Comment: No, I just get 'None'... maybe I am doing something wrong when saving the files?

Comment: I suggest you use the mongo shell to verify that images are saved in the picture collection. Then verify that the post.images collection contains references to the pictures.

Comment: Another issue: (I've never used mongoengine before so there might be things I don't understand)  In the [docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.EmbeddedDocumentField) it says that EmbeddedDocumentField's document_type must be a type that inherits from EmbeddedDocument (ie. does not have it's own collection) - your Picture class inherits from Document.

Comment: Did anybody solve this?  I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should do something like this:

```
class Picture(EmbeddedDocument):
    image = ImageField()

class Post(Document):
    ...
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'))
    user = ReferenceField('User', reverse_delete_rule='CASCADE')
    images = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Picture'))
```

To store a picture, append the picture to the `post.images` collection and call `post.save()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it should be EmbeddedDocument. I changed it, but this still doesn't solve my problem...